# Google Maps > Places Search not orienting

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Map API (v3) to create what is a glorified location/store find. Everything is working fine aside from the additional of the places search box (described here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox).

So far I've managed to connect the search box (attached) but can't get the map to orient itself or drop a pin on the selected location. Clearly this has something to do with the search box not binding itself to the map... I'm new to all this so that's my best guess anyway.

Any help would be most appreciated.

```
var map;
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            scrollwheel: false,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9, 151.2)
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);

        setMarkers(map, beaches);

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "loading..."
        });


        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));

  // [START region_getplaces]
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  // [END region_getplaces]

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
  // current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });

    }

    var beaches = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    function setMarkers(map, locations) {
        var image = {
            //url: '../assets/img/icon_mapPin.png',
            url: 'https://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/attachment/35489/map-pin.png',
            // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
            size: new google.maps.Size(20, 29),
            // The origin for this image is 0,0.
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 29)
        };

        var shape = {
            coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 29, 20, 29 , 1],
            type: 'poly'
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            var beach = locations[i];
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                shape: shape,
                title: beach[0],
                zIndex: beach[3],
                html: beach[0]
            });

            var contentString = '<div class="siteNotice">'+beach[1]+'</div>';

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is error reported:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: markers is not defined
```

`markers` array should be defined and set properly like

```
var map;

function initialize() {
    var markers = [];
    ...
```